# Setting up Kerberos authentication on an apache2 Web Server

Tags: authentication, apache2, debian, kerberos

I'm trying to set up a web server that will authenticate users using kerberos before displaying the page to the user.  I've followed some online instructions but when I reach the webpage and type in my credentials, the page will just reload the login window again, and make me login again. If I hit cancel on the login window, it shows me a 401 Error page saying I am not authorized to access the page.  It seems like my kerberos is not set up properly, but I have no way to tell.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post last few lines of Apache error log. This will show why authentication failed.

Answer (score 1):

What did you set up? You will require:

1. mod_auth_kerb configured in apache
2. a machine account for the server
3. an exported keytab for the server
4. a SPNEGO-capable client